# How can I register for Push Notifications in iOS after the user logs in?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

When a user opens my app for the first time, they are spammed with permission requests, one of these is for Push Notifications. I have seen a few posts of people referencing approaches in Swift but none in Xamarin.

My app can register and receive push notifications without a problem, but I would prefer to make the request for push notifications after the user has successfully logged in. Is this possible in the Xamarin Forms world?

I understand using the example on Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#connect-your-app-to-the-notification-hub) a lot if not all the code is in AppDelegate.cs. I lack the understanding of why it must be here, does anyone have any pointers or reading material to explain as to why here?

Any and all help will be highly appreciate.

**UPDATE**

So I'm slowly getting there now, I'm using an interface to call my `UserNotificationCenterDelegate` class in my iOS project from my shared code.

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options) {

        // Unsure if this line is required or not
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken) {
        base.RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(application, deviceToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
```

**UserNotification**

```
    public UserNotificationCenterDelegate() { }

    public void RegisterForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge, (approved, error) => {
            if (approved) {
                InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
            }
        });
    }

    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler) {
        base.WillPresentNotification(center, notification, completionHandler);

        // Do something with the notification
        Console.WriteLine("Active Notification: {0}", notification);

        // Tell system to display the notification anyway or use
        // `None` to say we have handled the display locally.
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }
```

So through a DependencyService I can call `RegisterForPushNotifiactions` but when accepting the Push Permission it should call `RegisterForRemoteNotifcations` in the AppDelegate.cs - but it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like all you need to do is move all the contents of `FinishedLaunching` inside the given example to wherever you want it to be called. The rest must still be in `AppDelegate` since it consist of overriding methods.

Comment: My understanding from that though, is my code would still be executed when the app runs? What I wish to do is only attempt to register for push notifications/request the permission when the user successfully logs in.

Comment: No. The code would be executed wherever and whenever you call it. Currently it is executed when app starts because you call it when app finishes launching. But you can call it whenever you want it. And once you call it your app will communicate the request with the operating system. The operating system will notify your app back through your application delegate which is designed to do so.

Comment: My apologies I misread what you said. I understand where you're coming from now. I've successfully got my Push Notification permission to appear on a different page now (instead of when the app launches). I'm just trying to overide `RegisterForRemoteNotifications` from a different class.

Comment: That will not be possible. You can only forward the call. Your app delegate will need to have access to the class you want to forward your call to. If there is no better way you can link them using static properties. So then delegate would call for instance AppDelegate.notificationListener.register So in this case notificationListener is a static property to which you would probably assign in some constructors like AppDelegate.notificationListener = this

Comment: I may have used the wrong words there, so I've updated my original post and I've actually got what I wanted to do working now. When I mentioned overriding `RegisterForRemoteNotifications` what I was refering to was this: `InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);`
This all works now. :)

Comment: How did you move the notification permission on different page ? @MattVon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to Request for Push Permission from inside the App Delegates. From the article that you followed, remove all the codes from within the following method, which asks for the push notification permission:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
```

Then, move that code into some other class/functions that you want to call later when you are ready to ask for the push permission. Like:

```
public static void CheckAndAskPushNotificationPermission()
{
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
    { UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                                                            (granted, error) =>
    {
        if (granted)
            InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
    });
} else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
    var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (
            UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
            new NSSet ());

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (pushSettings);
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications ();
} else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes (notificationTypes);
}

}
```

When ever, wherever you are ready to ask for permission:

```
PushHelperiOS.CheckAndAskPushNotificationPermission();
```

Leave the following methods intact in app delegates because you only can override them in there (based on your blog you are following):

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)

public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
```

Let me know if you have any confusions.

Comment: Gotcha, since I'm using Xamarin Forms I would what to access `CheckAndAskPushNotificationPermission` via an Interface, correct?

Comment: Correct, Create the Interface in your Shared then implement above implementation in your platforms then register and access them as a dependency service.

Comment: So I can call the my `RegisterForPushNotification`method via an Interface. Within that if the permissions have been approved it should call `RegisterForRemoteNotifications` which is being overridden in AppDelegate. However, it's not calling it.

Comment: Make sure to Delete an existing app from device before redeploying from VS.

Comment: I'm unsure what this would achieve, but I've done this but there are no differences. I've updated my original post to given a visual of my current code now. Hopefully this can provide you an insight what I'm doing.

Comment: Success, I've done it! My example above was working but I don't know the problem until I override `FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications`. I was using a test project which was hooked up to APS. So I moved my new code to my actual project using APS and it's worked exactly as I hoped!